# How to Delete Orphaned Domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, trust-relationship

I am trying to remove child domain from parent domain therefore follow below link
http://myblogs-amit.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-remove-default-trust_13.html

Step01 to Step04 Successfully done but unable to perform step06 error occurred

"Operation failed.Error Code: 0x5 Access is denied."

The box of “protect object from accidental deletion” is Grayed

Comment: Hi is your end goal to have both domains still active? or are you just looking to remove the child domain?

Answer (score 0):

How to remove orphaned domains from Active Directory
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230306

Typically, when the last domain controller for a domain is demoted, the administrator selects the This server is the last domain controller in the domain option in the DCPromo tool, which removes the domain meta-data from Active Directory. This article describes how to remove domain meta-data from Active Directory if this procedure is not used or if or all domain controllers are taken offline but not demoted first.

Removing Orphaned Domains from Active Directory

1. Determine the domain controller that holds the Domain Naming Master Flexible Single Master Operations (FSMO) role. To identify the server holding this role:
       Start the Active Directory Domains and Trusts Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in from the Administrative Tools menu.
       Right-click the root node in the left pane titled Active Directory Domains and Trusts, and then click Operations Master.
       The domain controller that currently holds this role is identified in the Current Operations Master frame.NOTE: If this changed recently, not all computer may have received this change yet due to replication.

For more information about FSMO roles, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
        197132 Windows 2000 Active Directory FSMO Roles

2. Verify that all servers for the domain have been demoted.
3. Open a Command Prompt.
4. At the command prompt, type: ntdsutil.
5. Type: *metadata cleanup*, and then press ENTER.
6. Type: *connections*, and then press ENTER. This menu is used to connect to the specific server on which the changes will occur. If the currently logged-on user is not a member of the Enterprise Admins group, alternate credentials can be supplied by specifying the credentials to use before making the connection. To do so, type: set creds domainname username password , and then press ENTER. For a null password, type: null for the password parameter.
7. Type: *connect to server servername* (where servername is the name of the domain controller holding the Domain Naming Master FSMO Role), and then press ENTER. You should receive confirmation that the connection is successfully established. If an error occurs, verify that the domain controller being used in the connection is available and that the credentials you supplied have administrative permissions on the server.
8. Type: *quit*, and then press ENTER. The Metadata Cleanup menu is displayed.
9. Type: *select operation target*, and then press ENTER.
10. Type: *list domains*, and then press ENTER. A list of domains in the forest is displayed, each with an associated number.
11. Type: *select domain number*, and then press ENTER, where number is the number associated with the domain to be removed.
12. Type: *quit*, and then press ENTER. The Metadata Cleanup menu is displayed.
13. Type: *remove selected domain*, and then press ENTER. You should receive confirmation that the removal was successful. If an error occurs, please refer to the Microsoft Knowledge Base for articles on specific error messages.
14. Type: *quit* at each menu to quit the NTDSUTIL tool. You should receive confirmation that the connection disconnected successfully.